# Custom session#create parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

To integrate my website to a partner website, I need to have custom parameter names :

By default, devise sessions#create parameters are :

`user[email]` and `user[password]`

(These parameters translate to a nested Hash into :user)

For my partner, I need to be able to respond to

`email` and `password`

I went through a lot of tries, and I ended to implement a custom `Devise::Strategy` and a custom `user#find_for_database_authentication` to be able to catch these parameters.

Devise::Strategies::CustomSso.rb

```
require 'devise/strategies/database_authenticatable'
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class CustomSso < DatabaseAuthenticatable

      def valid?
        params[:sso]=="true"
      end

      def authenticate!
        password = params[:password]
        resource  = password.present? && mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(params)
        hashed = false

        if validate(resource){ hashed = true; resource.valid_password?(password) }
          remember_me(resource)
          resource.after_database_authentication
          success!(resource)
        end

        mapping.to.new.password = password if !hashed && Devise.paranoid
        fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource
      end

    end
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(params)
    User.find_by(email: "#{params[:email]}")
  end
  ....
end
```

It works, but is there a better or simpler way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason**

The reason that authentication happens against "original" parameters is not because `ApplicationController` `before_action` callback runs late or request gets modified (restored) later, but because `devise` takes parameters not from controller params object.

Originally in Warden params will be taken from new [`Rack::Request`](https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/mixins/common.rb#L18), created from env (environment) value:

```
  # Convenience method to access the rack request.
  # :api: public
  def request
    @request ||= Rack::Request.new(@env)
  end # request
```

In `Devise` though, it's patched to new instance of [`ActionDispatch::Request`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb#L3) instead, so that's why changing request in routes.rb (see options below) will work.

```
module Warden::Mixins::Common
  def request
    @request ||= ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
  end
```

In fact, using ActionDispatch request allows to actually alter request params before Devise processing, see solution 4 below.

Then `params` are taken from that request (code from Warden Base mixin) to further extract values for authentication:

```
 # Convenience method to access the rack request params
 # :api: public
 def params
   request.params
 end # params
```

Authenticatable strategy by Devise has `params_auth_hash` helper to [extract](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb#L91) only needed parameters from all (scope is ~ model name, e.g. user)

```
  # Extract the appropriate subhash for authentication from params.
  def params_auth_hash
    params[scope]
  end
```

Although you can [configure](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L13) key names that will be taken from `params_auth_hash` in your Devise-based  model, you can't configure to not "cut" only `[scope]` portion of params

```
#   * +authentication_keys+: parameters used for authentication. By default [:email].
```

**Solutions**

Therefore there are several options available:

1) **Rewriting params** method (public in Warden common mixin, not params method of request or controller!) in your strategy to "patch" parameters there, e.g.

```
class CustomSso < DatabaseAuthenticatable
  def params 
    request.params[:user][:email] = request.params[:email]
    request.params
  end
```

2) **Rewrite params_auth_hash** method (private in `authenticatable` strategy by Devise) in the same place:

```
  def params_auth_hash
    params[scope][:email] = params[:email]
    params[scope]
    # just return full params and not [scope] here in your case?
  end
```

3) **Changing request params in routes**

Dirty hack by altering request parameters in rails route custom constraint (`config/routes.rb`). Add following before `devise_for :<model_name>`

```
post '/users/sign_in', constraints: lambda { |request| 
  if URL_IS_FOR_SSO? && request.params[:password] && request.params[:email]
      request.params[:user] = {password: request.params[:password], email: request.params[:email]}
  end
  false #doesn't apply this route, proceed to further routing
}
```

4) (best if working) **Change request parameters in application controller** `before_action`

You can also change name of the parameters passed in the request to satisfy Devise convention and then use default Devise strategy. You can use some method of rewriting, the simplest is putting filter inside `ApplicationController`.

*Important* - as a source of confusion, `params` method of ActionController is relevant to [StrongParamaters](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb) [concept](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) and completely different from request.params (which is basically just a hash).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_action :rewrite_param_names

  private

  # !! important - use request.params and not just params!!
  def rewrite_param_names
    if URL_IS_FOR_SSO? && request.params[:password] && request.params[:email]
      request.params[:user] = {password: request.params[:password], email: request.params[:email]}
    end
  end
end
```

This works because ActionDispatch::Request store reference to parameters hash in env header and allows updating this hash. [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L30):

```
   # Returns both GET and POST \parameters in a single hash.
      def parameters
        params = get_header("action_dispatch.request.parameters")
        return params if params

         ...
        set_header("action_dispatch.request.parameters", params)
        params
      end
```

To make before_action more focused, you can create custom controller for Devise and set it in parent_controller [setting](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/9a11586a724487dc98dddea0ab9c8afcc0e9439d/lib/devise.rb#L223) for Devise

```
 # The parent controller all Devise controllers inherits from.
 # Defaults to ApplicationController. This should be set early
 # in the initialization process and should be set to a string.
 mattr_accessor :parent_controller
 @@parent_controller = "ApplicationController"
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thx for your response. I tried something like this. Unfortunatly, rewritted parameters in before action are not visible in devise. If I check the content of params in devise, it's the same that I received from URL, not the rewritted .... I'm using Rails 4.2 and devise 4.0.

Comment: @oliviergg, can you try using `request.params` instead of `params` in `ApplicationController` before_action? It seems to solve the issue for me

Comment: Very nice explanation ! Thx you very much. I wasn't aware that devise use request.params and that it was not the same as params ...

Comment: It seems that params in controller is used for StrongParamaters concept (with permit thing) and is only used by (rails) controllers. So it's a wrapper around parameters, available for controllers only. And something outside of controllers uses request parameters through some Request object implementation (which, meanwhile, can differ too).